# Unable to build the correct ffnn on pybrain

Tags: python, pybrain

I have trained a ffnn to fit a unknown function with pybrain. I build the ffnn like this

```
net = buildNetwork(1, 2, 1,hiddenclass=TanhLayer)
```

I said to pybrain to print the params of the net with the command

```
print net.params
```

and pybrain return me the params

```
(1.76464967 , 0.46764103 , 1.63394395 ,-0.95327762 , 1.19760151, -1.20449402, -1.34050959)
```

now I want to use this fitted function in another script. I tried

```
def netp(Q):
    net = buildNetwork(1, 2, 1,hiddenclass=TanhLayer)
    net._setParameters=(1.76464967 , 0.46764103 , 1.63394395 ,-0.95327762 , 1.19760151, -1.20449402, -1.34050959)
    arg=1.0/float(Q)
    p=float(net.activate([arg]))
    return p
```

The problem is that the values returned from the nets are completely out of mind. example

```
 0.0749046652125 1.0
-2.01920546405 0.5
-1.54408069672 0.333333333333
 1.05895945271 0.25
-1.01314347373 0.2
 1.56555648799 0.166666666667
 0.0824497539453 0.142857142857
 0.531176423655 0.125
 0.504185707604 0.111111111111
 0.841424535805 0.1
```

where the first column if the output of the net, and the second the input. The output of the net has to be close to the input value.
What's the problem? Where I am doing wrong? It's a problem of over fitting or a I am missing something?

Comment: for what input you get *out of mind* output? please also include packages versions

Comment: I am feeding the function with probabilities and the net returning me negative values or bigger then 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typo:

```
net._setParameters=(1.76464967 , 0.46764103 , 1.63394395 ,-0.95327762 , 1.19760151, -1.20449402, -1.34050959)
```

This line effectively replaces private `_setParamethers` method with a tuple. Try if replacing this line with

```
net._setParameters([1.76464967 , 0.46764103 , 1.63394395 ,-0.95327762 , 1.19760151, -1.20449402, -1.34050959])
```

will help.

Second, don't see reasons for `1/Q` operation, so simple

```
>>> def netp(Q): return float(net.activate([Q]))
>>> for i in inp:
...   print '{}\t{:.5f}'.format(i, netp(i))
```

yields

```
1.0      0.97634
0.5      0.46546
0.33333  0.29013
0.25     0.20762
0.2      0.16058
0.16666  0.13042
0.14285  0.10952
0.125    0.09421
0.11111  0.08254
0.1      0.07335
```

Comment: no, the problem is the same, and now i am noting that the outputs values are random.

Comment: I want that this repetitive calculation is done by inside the function.

Comment: @emanuele no, not why in function, why at all. see edit in my answer

Comment: because Q si reprensenting the odd. Then the inverse is the probability.

Comment: @emanuele You got it wrong, 1/0.01=100 can't be probability. You have linear layers in and out and tanh inside, so feeding something big as 1/0.01 you'll definetely wont get back something small. It have + or - sign depending on params, but never will be small by absolute value

Comment: @emanuele and random values result from random net params. you can try to print net.params inside your old function (before fix) to be sure)